# format a DateTime in php with format "JJJJ-MM-TTTss:mmZZZ"

Tags: php, date, datetime, format

I'm trying to format a date like Google specifies to format it

the format specified by Google is  :

```
" JJJJ-MM-TTTss:mmZZZ "
```

What I tried so far is:

```
  var_dump(date_format($date,'Y-M-D H:m:s'));
```

results in

```
  "2013-Aug-Wed 18:08:37"
```

when I try to uses googles format like

```
 var_dump(date_format($date,'JJJJ-MM-TTTss:mmZZZ'));
```

it results in

```
 JJJJ-AugAug-CESTCESTCEST3737:0808720072007200"
```

I have no idea what it should look like, any help?

thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked the related manual pages of the functions you are trying to use?

Comment: See the examples in the [documentation for `date_format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) (under *Procedural Style*). The list of available formats can be found [here](http://php.net/date)

Comment: i cant find the information what "mmZZZ" should be for example, if somebody could add an example date-string with the format 'JJJJ-MM-TTTss:mmZZZ'

Comment: Start at the documentation of google and see what format is expected. After that check the docs of date_format. On that page you will find links you need to follow for the format. As it currently stands it looks like you are just guessing and making up stuff instead of actually looking things up in our fine manual.

Comment: @john Smith, i added an example in my answer.

Comment: the solution was 'Y-m-d\TH:i:sP'

Answer (score 2):

What about this?

```
$date = date_create();
print date_format($date, 'Y-m-d\TH:iT');
```

Output:

```
2014-03-24T10:43CET
```

Comment: OP uses the `DateTime` class. I suggest fixing this answer to take this into account.

Comment: this is the correct way : 'Y-m-d\TH:i:sP'

Answer (score -1):

As i understand you are reading non english version of google manual, in english this date format looks like

```
YYYY-MM-DDThh:mmTZD
```

and example of this is

```
1997-07-16T19:20+01:00
```

You can try to produce this in PHP like this

```
echo date("Y-m-d\TH:s", time());
```

Comment: While correct, this does not answer the question that was asked.

Comment: correct is : 'Y-m-d\TH:i:sP'